# Как удалить все таблицы из схемы

Tags: sql, windows, oracle, cmd, oracle12c

Как удалить все таблицы из схемы?

Например, запускаемый cmd-скрипт в Windows, создает подключение к указанной схеме, а затем создает разные таблицы и наполняет данными.

А как написать команду, которая проверяла бы :

- если есть в схеме какие либо таблицы,
- создать копию существующей схемы
- очистить схему от таблиц (таблицы имеют отношения)
- создать новые таблицы

И если кто сможет написать такой скрипт, прокомментируйте команды.

Answer (score 2):

Включите в скрипт следующие команды (например, для схемы HR):

```sh
# вернёт кол-во таблиц в схеме
echo -e "set head off\n select count (1) from user_tables;"|\
    sqlplus -l -s hr/hr@srv/pdb1

# создаст полную копию схемы
expdp system/pass@srv/pdb1 schemas=hr \
    directory=data_pump_dir dumpfile=hrlast.dmp logfile=exphr.log

# удалит схему полностью
echo "drop user hr cascade;"|\
    sqlplus -l system/pass@srv/pdb1

# создаст схему HR со всеми таблицами, НО БЕЗ ДАННЫХ
impdp system/pass@srv/pdb1 content=metadata_only \
    directory=data_pump_dir dumpfile=hrlast.dmp logfile=imphr.log
```